# Having trouble with my polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Could someone explain to me why I am getting these errors on my coding when it comes to the main method project5 class. `thearray[count++]` keeps giving me errors, and I am not entirely sure where I made my error. I've been stuck on it for awhile now. Some guidance would be nice.

Here is my main method:

```
public class Project5 {



private Shape [] thearray = new Shape[100]; 

public static void main (String [] args) {

Project5 tpo = new Project5();

tpo.run();

} 

public void run () {

int count = 0;

thearray[count++] = new Circle(20, 20, 40);

thearray[count++] = new Triangle(70, 70, 20, 30);

thearray[count++] = new Rectangle(150, 150, 40, 40);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {
thearray[i].display(); 
}

int offset = 0;

double totalarea = 0.0;

while (thearray[offset] != null) { 

totalarea = totalarea + thearray[offset].area(); 

offset++;

} 

System.out.println("The total area for " + offset + " Shape objects is     " + totalarea);

} 

}
```

Here is my `Circle` class:

```
public class Circle {

private double radius;

public Circle()  {
   radius = 1.0;
}    
public Circle(double newRadius)  {

   radius = 1.0;
   setRadius(newRadius);
}
public void setRadius(double newRadius) {
   if(newRadius > 0) {
   radius = newRadius;

    } 
   else {
       System.out.println("Error: " 
               + newRadius + " is a bad radius value.");
   }
  } 
 public double getRadius()  {
   return radius;

 }

 public double getArea() {
    return radius * radius * Math.PI;
 }

}
```

and here is my Shape class:

```
abstract class Shape{

int x = 1;
int y = 1;

public int getX() {
return x; 

}
public void setX(int x) {
this.x = x;

}

public int getY() {
return y; 

}
public void setY(int y) {
this.y = y;

}
public Shape(int x, int y) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

public void display() {

}
public abstract double area();

}
```

I would post my triangle and rectangle class, but I figured this would be enough to at least have it explained where I am messing up.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You are creating Circle with 3 arguments in the constructor, but in the Circle class itself the constructor only takes one argument

Comment: Hi Enrique where is the parameterized constructor which accepts 3 or 4 arguments in your Circle,Rectangle,Triangle classes.

Comment: I know this will sound stupid but I'm still fairly novice at this. Where exactly would I have to fix it so it could read it correctly. Just trying to make sense of this

Comment: your code is not even compiling, there is no such Circle constructor taking 3 int as argument

Answer (score -1):

I looked at your Circle class and the constructor currently only takes one argument. However, when you create a Circle you are specifying 3 arguments.

Circle should probably extend from Shape and the first two parameters are then the x and y position of the shape, correct? If this is the case, change your class as follows:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

   private double radius;

   public Circle(int x, int y)  {
      super(x, y);
      radius = 1.0;
   }    
   public Circle(int x, int y, double newRadius)  {
      super(x, y);
      setRadius(newRadius);
   }
   ...etc
```

Comment: Also, try to solve your problem one step at a time. First try to get your Circle class working perfectly, then add the other shapes to your main program.